# Adding Images with JSPDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, jspdf

Am using JSPDF to generate PDF in javascript, when I add Images and I generate the PDF file, the PDF file does not display the image until I generate the PDF a second time. Here is my code below

```
            var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');

            var res = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(document.getElementById("data-table-committee"));


            var header = function (data) {
                doc.setFontSize(18);
                doc.setTextColor(40);
                doc.setFontStyle('normal');
                doc.text("Committee Count List", data.settings.margin.left, 80);
                console.log('adding image');
                doc.addImage(headerImgData, 'PNG', data.settings.margin.left, 20, 150, 30);
                console.log('adding image done');
            };

            var options = {
                beforePageContent: header,
                margin: {
                    top: 50
                },
                startY: doc.autoTableEndPosY() + 20
            };

            doc.autoTable(res.columns, res.data, options);

            doc.save("Committee Count List.pdf");
```

What am I doing wrong and How can I get my image to be displayed the first time I generate the PDF

Answer (score 0):

You can also create pdf using pdfkit. Here is the code that generates pdf with an image.

```
var PDFDocument = require ('pdfkit');
var fs = require('fs');
doc = new PDFDocument
doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('output.pdf'))
doc.image('E:/sii/nodejs/uploads/public/uploads/test.jpg', {
   fit: [250, 300],
   align: 'center',
   valign: 'center'
});
doc.end()
```